# mobile site layout trouble

Tags: html, layout, mobile, css, media-queries

I'm fiddling with a mobile specific stylesheet where, using a media query, I am using a sheet called "styles_mobile.css" to add style specific to mobile visitors.

I wish there was a way to use only the mobile stylesheet in case of a mobile visitor as opposed to in addition to the original stylesheet - an independent stylesheet.

Anyway, since I cannot find a way without code (I cannot code, only light client side skills) I am having to fiddle with a mobile layout.

It appears that no what property value I try to correct for in the mobile stylesheet I cannot style so that the content fits the screen width only. Somewhere there is a rule that is making my mobile html appear longer than 100% of screen width and this could be a number of things taken from the original stylesheet.

The URL is here if anyone happens to be able to view with a mobile device, which should be using the "styles_mobile.css" sheet. I have added a solid outline to all elements so the issue is visible:

http://tinyurl.com/7ywoqpf

At the top of the page there is clearly an element stretching out the screen from width, or min-width, property values from the main stylesheet. No matter how much I try to correct these I cannot :-(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can set a minimum width for each of the stylesheets to prevent it interfering with any width below what you want it to work for.
Should look similar to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 810px) and (min-width: 721px)" href="tabstyle.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

We using this method

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/common.css">
<!--Responsive style sheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1407px)" href="css/tab-only.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px)" href="css/phone-only.css">
```

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure what that does? Does that make the mobile style sheets independent? Doesn't look like it